# Use Orchard Core to build modular application on ASP.NET Core with Identity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, orchard-modules

I want to use Orchard Core to build a modular application, one of the modular application is using Identity Framework.

https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore.Samples

I modify the sample code from Orchard's website. I can access the route "modular_project_name/Home/Index"  from another project, but I can't access the route "modular_project_name/Identity/Account/Login" (which is a login view in Identity Framework).

Is there any suggestion for this issue? If there is please help me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @KenJ, try to use F12 developer tools to check is there any error when access the Identity page? Besides, about the identity page, whether it is generated via the Scaffold Identity? You can also check the application folder whether you can find this identity page or not? If the identity page doesn't exist, try to add them. And if you are using Scaffold Identity to generate the page, the relate identity page is razor page, so you need to configure route to for them, for example, add `endpoints.MapRazorPages();` in the Configure method, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yOju.png).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.